# Unity3d AdMob rewarded ad not showing

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, ads

I am doing some simple app with two buttons... first button is sending request for Awarded (test) ad and then second shows the ad.

Here is my code:

```
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class adManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    RewardBasedVideoAd rewardedAd;

    public void Start()
    {
        rewardedAd = RewardBasedVideoAd.Instance;
        requestVideo();
    }


    public void requestVideo()
    {
        Debug.Log("Video Requested!");
        string adID = "My ad ID";
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .AddTestDevice(AdRequest.TestDeviceSimulator)       // Simulator.
            .AddTestDevice("BD6E7C35B6F8FA70")  // My test device.
            .Build();

        rewardedAd.LoadAd(request, adID);
    }

    public void showBannerAd()
    {
        if (rewardedAd.IsLoaded())
        {
            Debug.Log("AdAvailible!");
            rewardedAd.OnAdRewarded += HandleOnAdRewarded;
            rewardedAd.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("AdNotAvailible!");
        }
    }

    public void HandleOnAdRewarded(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.Log("You are rewarded!"); 
    }

    public event EventHandler<Reward> OnAdRewarded;
}
```

Is something wrong with my code or something else? 
I tried interstitial and banner ad and they WORKED.

Thanks for help.

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: no error.... ad is just not showing... when i checked the log i get output "AdNotAvailible"